# How to use a dynamic action: PL/SQL statement to UPDATE current row in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, process, apex, session-state

I'm trying to create a merchant application form that has the ability to store session values (created date, created by, last updated, etc) as well as all of the page items that the user enters (name, accountid, etc). I've got the user entered values stored just fine, but I can't figure out how to store the session values.

My first idea was to create an "after submit" process that involved a PL/SQL statement to update the session values. [Update Table PL/SQL Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibfyk.png). But that updated all of the rows in my table with the same session state values, when I only need it to update the current row.

So then I updated that query with the minimal PL/SQL code that I know to try and set a condition to only update that row. `where rowid = (select max(rowid)  from app_form_submission);` Thinking that the 'max(rowid)' would be the most current row. When I added this condition none of the session state values were updated in my table.

I tried using the same query as a dynamic action attatched to the submit button but it gave me the same result. Does anyone know how to reference the current row in PL/SQL or maybe a better way to get these session state values stored in my table? I looked into using SQL cursors but I'm afraid it's going over my head.

Thanks!

Comment: How can we comment on, or spot the error in, code that we cannot see?  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @EdStevens I apologize but I'm a little confused on what other code I would need to include. I have the PL/SQL stored in the image link and then I listed the where clause (which is attached to the PL/SQL code) in the paragraph below.

Comment: DId you read the link I gave you? Especially the part where it says "DO NOT use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then format it as code. This helps others more easily read and test your code."

Comment: Your assumption *thinking that the 'max(rowid)' would be the most current row* is absolutely **FALSE**. It may turnout that way but it is not guaranteed.  It may even change; suppose your dba reorg the table, or moves it to a different table space? The rowid will change and what they become is unpredictable. HINT: Never depend upon things you have absolutely no control over. Even if guaranteed in a particular release it just might change in the next one.

Comment: As far as posting your code post it as formatted text. See [Why not upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also take a few minutes and take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/) and to review [ask].